# QOpenGLWidget: Drawing at 60FPS while not interfering with its existing timing?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, frame-rate

I'm writing a shader editor using C++, Qt, and OpenGL.  I want the rendered scene to be interactive, and I want the user to be able to use variables from the surrounding environment, like mouse coordinates or window dimensions.

As it stands, every time there's basically any sort of input (mouse moved, window brought to focus, key pressed, etc.) the OpenGL widget is redrawn.  This is how Qt's rendering works normally.

However, I also want to let the user use regularly-changing inputs **whose values don't depend on user interaction**, like the system time, random numbers, and possibly even the webcam.  To do this in a meaningful way, I'd have to update the screen at a regular interval (which I'll probably let the user customize, as a matter of fact).

If user input triggers a render while a timer does as well, or vice versa, then I will be wrestling with race conditions.  **How do I avoid this?**

Comment: *If user input triggers a render while a timer does as well, or vice versa, then I will be wrestling with race conditions.* Why do you think so? Whenever stuff changes that the scene depends on, simply `update()` the gl widget. This posts the update event to the event queue, and such events are compressed, so no matter how often you call `update`, there will be only one re-render once the event loop is back in control. Simple. If you're asking for something else, please update the question with relevant details or code. "Rendered scene" - where? On a `QGLWidget` or `QOpenGLWidget`, or?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want a rendering queue. Whenever a user, or the system, triggers a render, you would push that into the queue. You would then have a single rendering thread that polls the queue at regular intervals to initiate a render. However, I don't see how this would be a race condition, since a call to render should update the screen regardless of what has been changed.
Having the queue would also help you optimize your code as you can avoid performing multiple consecutive unnecessary rendering calls.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I don't need a queue as every render call will be rendering the same scene (for now). This is more of a Qt/OpenGL question than a general rendering one, I suppose.

Comment: Don't understand the question then. You asked: "If user input triggers a render while a timer does as well, or vice versa, then I will be wrestling with race conditions. How do I avoid this?". When dealing with race conditions, regardless of the context, you wan to either use immutable structures, thread-safe structures, or locks around thread-unsafe calls. Nowhere in your question that I can see does it ask anything specific to QT/OpenGL.

Comment: I guess I might not be using the proper terminology; I'm not using threading explicitly, though I have no doubt a timer would.  By "race conditions" I mean "what if the user's mouse movement triggers a render while already in the middle of a timer-called render?"

Answer (score 0):

Use a [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html). This will trigger repaint events on the same Qt thread as the other update events, so you don't need to worry about race conditions. For example, in your QOpenGLWidget-derived constructor:

```
auto pTimer = new QTimer(this);
connect(pTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &QOpenGLWidget::update); 
pTimer->start(1000 / 60.0);
```